# Нужна помощь с gtk+ и записью в файл. Пишу на linux mint

Tags: c, файлы, gui, gtk, gtk+

В файл записывается почему то только "3200000000" и всё, не смотря на то, что я ввожу. Допустим ввожу 123, в файл должны записаться аски коды каждого введённого символа, а записывается всегда 3200000000.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void zapis(GtkWidget *ok_button, GtkWidget *password_entry, gpointer data)
{
  FILE *f=fopen("gtk.txt", "w");
  if(fopen==NULL) printf("Error");

  int i;
  char password[10]=" ";

  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
  fprintf(f, "%d", password[i]);

  fclose(f);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *password_label;
  GtkWidget *password_entry;
  GtkWidget *ok_button;
  GtkWidget *hbox;
  GtkWidget *vbox;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  window=gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Register");
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);

  g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
  GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  password_label = gtk_label_new("Password:");
  password_entry = gtk_entry_new();
  gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(password_entry), TRUE);
  ok_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Ok");
  g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(ok_button), "clicked",
  GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(zapis), password_entry);

  hbox = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 5);
  vbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 10);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), password_label, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), password_entry, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), ok_button, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);


  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я немного изменил, добавил запись в файл в функцию main, теперь записываются просто нули "000000000"

Comment: дык ты и записываешь ascii код пробела и ещё 9 asci кодов символа '\0'.

Comment: @Fat-Zer и что мне сделать с этим?Как мне закинуть в массив введённые символы?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю в вопросе подразумевалось что-то такое:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void onClick(GtkButton *ok_button, gpointer data)
{
  FILE *f=fopen("gtk.txt", "w");

  if (!f) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error");
    return;
  }

  GtkWidget *entry = data;

  const gchar *pswd = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY(entry));
  guint16 len = gtk_entry_get_text_length (GTK_ENTRY(entry));
  for(guint16 i=0; i<len; i++) {
    fprintf(f, "%c: %u\n", pswd[i], (unsigned)pswd[i]);
  }

  fclose(f);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *password_label;
  GtkWidget *password_entry;
  GtkWidget *ok_button;
  GtkWidget *hbox;
  GtkWidget *vbox;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  window=gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Register");
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);

  g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
  GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  password_label = gtk_label_new("Password:");
  password_entry = gtk_entry_new();
  gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(password_entry), TRUE);
  ok_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Ok");
  g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(ok_button), "clicked",
    GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(onClick), password_entry);

  hbox = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 5);
  vbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 10);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), password_label, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), password_entry, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), ok_button, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```